# from binary data to wxbitmap

Tags: python, image, binary, wxpython

I have a device which stores a grayscale image as a series of 8 bit unsigned integer values. I want to write a python program to read these images from a file and show them using wxBitmap. I have a code that works, but it seems inefficient due to a lot of conversions between formats.

Any suggestions for a faster code are highly appreciated.

My current code:

```
imagearray=numpy.fromfile(file=self.f, dtype=numpy.uint8, count=npixels).reshape(Height, Width)[::-1]
pilimage = Image.fromarray(imagearray)
rgb= pilimage.convert('RGB')
rgbdata = rgb.tostring()
WxBitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(Width,Height)            
WxBitmap.CopyFromBuffer(rgbdata)
output=WxBitmap
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a wxBitmap directly from a numpy array.
[This is an example from wxPyWiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages):

```
import wx, numpy

def GetBitmap( self, width=32, height=32, colour = (0,0,0) ):
        array = numpy.zeros( (height, width, 3),'uint8')
        array[:,:,] = colour
        image = wx.EmptyImage(width,height)
        image.SetData( array.tostring())
        wxBitmap = image.ConvertToBitmap()       # OR:  wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
        return wxBitmap
```